# How to implement heritage with knockoutJS objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a model consisting of a `project` object, a `text` object and a `setting` object. The `settings` object can hold values for both `projects` and `texts`.

A `text` is always coupled to a `project`. Thus it should inherit the `project`s `settings` (if any). However if the `text` itself has `settings`, the user should be able to choose between using the project default or the text-specific `settings`.

The problem I'm having in my project is that updating the text local setting is also updating the project default settings. I guess this has to do with the observables relation, but so far I have been unable to find the connection.

Here's my code:

```
Text = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.textID = data.textID;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    self.projectID = data.projectID;

    // settings
    self.settings = ko.observable();          // initiated with "each" loop hook-up in viewmodel.
    self.project = ko.observable();            // initiated with "each" loop hook-up in viewmodel.
    self.projectSettings = ko.computed(function () {
        var project = self.project();
        if (project) {
            var proset = project.settings();
            return proset;
        }
        return null;
    });
    self.useProjectSettings = ko.observable(data.useProjectSettings || true);
    self.hasLocalSettings = ko.observable(false); // initiated with each loop hook-up in viewmodel.

    self.activeSettings = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.useProjectSettings() ? self.projectSettings() : self.settings();
    });

    return self;
};

Project = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.projectID = data.projectID;
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title);

    // settings
    self.settings = ko.observable();

    return self;
};

Setting = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.settingID = data.settingID;
    self.projectID = data.projectID;
    self.textID = data.textID;

    self.isVisible = ko.observable(data.isVisible);
    self.isProjectDefault = ko.observable(data.isProjectDefault || true);

    return self;
};

ViewModel = function (myprojects, mysettings, mytexts) {
    var self = this,
        koEach = ko.utils.arrayForEach, koFirst = ko.utils.arrayFirst, koFilter = ko.utils.arrayFilter;

    self.selectedText = ko.observable();

    //data - load
    self.Projects = ko.observableArray(
         ko.utils.arrayMap(myprojects, function (item) {
             return new Project(item);
         }));
    self.Settings = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(mysettings, function (item) {
            return new Setting(item);
        }));
    self.Texts = ko.observableArray(
         ko.utils.arrayMap(mytexts, function (item) {
             return new Text(item);
         }));

    //alert("self.Projects()[0].projectID=" + self.Projects()[0].projectID );


    // hook up 'settings' on 'project'
    koEach(self.Settings(), function (s) {

        if (s.isProjectDefault()) {
            var project = koFirst(self.Projects(), function (p) {
                return p.projectID === s.projectID;
            });
            if (project) {
                project.settings(s);
            }
        }
    });

    //alert("self.Texts()[0].textID=" + self.Texts()[0].textID + ", self.Texts()[0].title()=" + self.Texts()[0].title() );

    //hook up 'project' on 'texts'
    koEach(self.Texts(), function (t) {
        var project = koFirst(self.Projects(), function (p) {
            return p.projectID === t.projectID;
        });
        t.project(project);
        // initiate default publishingSettings for textbatch
        var initsettings = project.settings();
        t.settings(initsettings);
    });

    // hook up 'settings' on 'text'
    koEach(self.Settings(), function (s) {
        if (!s.isProjectDefault()) {
            var text = koFirst(self.Texts(), function (t) {
                return t.textID === s.textID;
            });
            if (text) {
                text.settings(s);
            }
        }
    });
};



// console log
var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";
console = {
    log: function (text) {
        $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
};

// input
var projects = [{ projectID: 0, title: 'project 0' }, { projectID: 1, title: 'project 1' }];
var settings = [
    { settingID: 0, projectID: 1, textID: null, isVisible: true, isProjectDefault: true },
    { settingID: 1, projectID: null, textID: 0, isVisible: true, isProjectDefault: false },
    { settingID: 2, projectID: 1, textID: 1, isVisible: false, isProjectDefault: false }
];
var texts = [{ textID: 0, projectID: 0, title: 'first text' }, { textID: 1, projectID: 1, title: 'second text' }];

// binding
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(projects, settings, texts));
```

Here´s my HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.Texts, optionsCaption: 'choose...', optionsText: 'title', value: selectedText"></select>
<br/>

Selected:   <span data-bind="text: $root.selectedText().title"></span><br>
Selected2:   <span data-bind="text: $root.selectedText().title"></span><br>
TextID:   <span data-bind="text: selectedText().textID"></span><br>
<hr/>    

<div data-bind="with: $root.selectedText">  
    <h2 data-bind="text:title"></h2>
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useProjectSettings" />Use project settings
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    Settings for text '<span data-bind="text: title"></span>' (id='<span data-bind="value: textID"></span>').<br/><br/>    
    <div class="pubset" data-bind="css: {'unabled' : useProjectSettings() }"> 
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class="checkbox">
               <label>
                   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="enable: !useProjectSettings(),checked: activeSettings().isVisible"/>
                   Show text
               </label>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With my example code here, it seems I also have another problem, as it's not progressing to the second `<span>` node. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/h31sLopp/).

Comment: I feel like your written explanation of the structure of your objects and the actual code structure are different.

Comment: It seems like the passed in data structures are only related by an integer ID. Is it possible to actually relate the data hierarchically via nested properties? Then you shouldn't need look up properties.

Comment: If the property is getting bubbled, that means your observable is referenced. So make a new copy before assigning the observable directly from one item to other, if you don't want that to happen

Comment: If you're capable of changing the data structure, I would definitely suggest that you do. [I tore apart your JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/67xva46y/5/) and restructured the models to be hierarchical. In this example, your nested properties don't need to have any knowledge of their parent which removes a lot of complexity.

Comment: Your initialization of isProjectDefault is always true.